# Why are mobs disappearing in my Hardcore world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was making an iron farm and I named a zombie to keep it from despawning. However, for some reason, it keeps going invisible to me. Some of my villagers do that as well.

I still hear the mobs that are invisible, the zombie deals damage to me when I'm close but I can't see him nor my other villagers. When I log out and re-login I see them until I move away from the chunks then they are invisible but I still hear them and stuff, can someone help?

Is it because I started the world on 1.16.1 and then changed to 1.16.4?

Comment: Seems like a server-client desync issue. It shouldn't prevent the farm from working, but if playing hardcore it may become an issue to survival.

Comment: its not just the farm some other mobs hit me and I cant see them, most are zombies

Comment: Yes, I guessed so. I wish I knew how to solve the problem. Check your Video options after loading the world, "Entity distance" at the bottom. Set it to something like 125%. If that doesn't help, I honestly don't know.

Comment: Did SF’s solution work?

Comment: Do you by any chance have Optifine? I had the same issue and it turns out optifine causes the mobs to disappear.

Answer (score -2):

Just wanted to say, maybe it is something that is wrong with the game files. Is it possible to reinstall Minecraft Java? If yes, try that. If that doesn't work, then do what SF said. Hope that helps!